# Shortcuts for pasting drivers

Tags: animation, shortcut, drivers

Recently I found out that I can introduce drivers in a very simplified method;

- copy a full path with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and
- paste this to any Number buttons with an # inserted at the beginning.

CAUTION : This seems to be an improper method since it produces some warnings at the driver editor.

My interest here is **whether there is a hot key to skip the "insert # at the beginning"**.
As you might know, pasting a number to a number button can be accomplished simply by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> hot key, and I am curious if there is one for inserting drivers.

Thanks.

[image: this]

Comment: It's a warning to say, in as much as this may work, it's better practice to add that property as a driver variable.  If the driving property is on the same object eg driving object scale with its x location would use `self.location.x` and check the "use self" checkbox.   The path `bpy.data.objects["Arrow"].rotation_euler[0]` will break if object is renamed, and needs to be updated if duplicating the object and its dirvers, else it will be driven by the original.

Comment: I knew how to remove the warning but didn't know why this produces one. I'll bear in mind. Thanks.